# How can I insertRow in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I have a button in a `viewController` which will trigger an alert, and I want it to automatically fill the string(parameter) and date in a cell in another `tableViewController`. This is what I did in `viewController`:

```
let applyButton: UIButton = {
                let button = UIButton(type: .system)
                ...
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showAlert), for: .touchUpInside)
                return button
 }()

@objc func showAlert() {
        let applyText = text
        let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Do you want to add it to management?" + applyText, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                
        refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    print("Handle Cancel Logic here")
                    refreshAlert .dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}))
        
        refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    print("Handle Ok logic here")
                    managementViewController().autoHandleAddTab(text: applyText)
}))
    self.present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is what I did in `tableViewController`(called managementViewController):

```
struct Todo {
    var todo: String
    var date: Date
}

fileprivate var todos:[Todo] = []

func autohandleAddTab(text: String) {
        guard text != "" else {return}
        self.todos.append(Todo(todo: text, date: Date()))
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.todos.count - 1, section: 0)
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

I also have a button in `tableViewController` which allows to manually add a note, and that one works well. When I want it to call this autohandleAddTab function, the length of `todos` change to 0 and the IndexPath is [0, 0]. When I manually add notes again, it continues to count based on the number of notes I manually added before. The note that I want to add to `tableView` doesn't show, but the ones I manually added are still there. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: If you are using storyboard then `managementViewController()` –  by the way name classes always with starting capital letter – is not the instance in the storyboard. You have to use a segue or instantiate the controller from the storyboard. And delete `begin-/endUpdates()`. It has no effect if only one insert operation is performed.

Comment: Hi vadian, thank you for your comment. I am not using storyboard. I checked segue, it is said `end point of a segue is the view controller you want to display`. But I want to start at a button in ViewController and end at a TableViewController.